# Ajax Request is Not Working in spring-mvc project

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, mariadb

I'm working on the `Spring-Mvc project`. I used `DAO` and `CONTROLLER` to get `DB` data and set output.

My view is made up of `JSP` and `JS`.

I have to put `DB` data in `JS` file. So I tried to solve it through `Ajax` but failed.

**DAO.java**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.point.service.game.config.SqlSessionFactoryDao;


@Service
public class ADao {

    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public ADao() {
        sqlSessionFactory = SqlSessionFactoryDao.getSqlSessionFactory();
    }




    public List<Map<Object,Object>> selectAllPayment() {
        SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        List<Map<Object,Object>> payments = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
        try {
        payments =  session.selectList("AdminPaymentDao.selectAllPayment");
        System.out.println("payments: " + payments);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        }catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return payments;
    }

}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import net.point.service.game.admin.payment.collection.ADao;

@Controller
public class Controller {

    private static Logger logger =  (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminPaymentController.class);

    @Autowired
    ADao aDao;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/adminRequestCharge", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  Map<String, Object> selectAllPayment() {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        logger.info("selectAllPayment start~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg");
        try {
        List<Map<Object, Object>> resultList = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
        resultList = aDao.selectAllPayment();
        for (Object list : resultList) {
            System.out.println("resultList:" + resultList);
        }
        result.put("jqgrid_data", resultList);
        }catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**js file**

```js
$(function(){

    //ajax
    $("#chargeRequestList").submit(function() {

        let queryData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url:"/adminRequestCharge",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
            data: queryData
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    })


    setRequestList(jqgrid_data);

    // grid resize
    $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function() {
        $("#chargeRequestList").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(".grid-cover").width());
    })

});



function setRequestList(jqgrid_data){
    jQuery("#chargeRequestList").jqGrid({
        data : jqgrid_data,
...
```

The form of value that I want:

```js
var jqgrid_data = [{
    seq: '1512',
    status : '0',
    value : '10,000',
    purchase_means : '1001',
    paid : '20',
    reg_date : '2019-06-24 12:43:33',
    pay_status : '0',
    paid_date : '2019-06-08 10:33:23',
    func : '1'
},
{
...
}
```

There are many things that I've never been familiar with before with `springs` and that I'm not fully familiar with `Java` and `Ajax`.

It may be a basic mistake because there are many things that are lacking,

I need your soluction

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to insert url to match the value of the controller as shown in the code below. url must not be equal to the value of View.

```js
$.ajax({
url:"/ChargeData",
type: “POST”,
dataType: “json”,
data: data,
success: function(result) {
console.log(result.jqgrid_data);    
setRequestList(result.jqgrid_data)
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**From your sample ajax dataset:**

```
[
{
   seq: '1512',
    status : '0',
    value : '10,000',
    purchase_means : '1001',
    paid : '20',
    reg_date : '2019-06-24 12:43:33',
    pay_status : '0',
    paid_date : '2019-06-08 10:33:23',
    func : '1'
    },
    ....
    ]
```

Now create a class, declare its fields  with same name of the keys of jsonObject i,e,

```
public class YourDto{
   private String seq;
   private String status;
   ....
   ...
}
```

Now replace your Controller method declaration with this:

```
 @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/adminRequestCharge", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  Map<String, Object> selectAllPayment(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody List<YourDto> yourDataList, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //your logic here;
    .....
}
```

Hope this helps.